# Simple java timer not working

Tags: java

I am new to programming and i used following code to run a timer. When this method is called with `boolean run = true`it is working fine but not stops when `boolean run = false`. How can i solve this ?

```
    private void countTime(boolean run){
        new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                int mm = 00;
                int hh = 00;
                while(run){
                    for (int i=1 ;i<61 ;i++){
                        try{
                            int ss = i;
                            Thread.sleep(1000);
                            if (ss == 60){
                                mm += 1;
                                if (mm == 60){
                                }
                            }
                            if (mm == 60){
                                hh += 1;
                                mm = 0;
                            }
                            if (ss < 10){
                                lblClock.setText(Integer.toString(hh) + ":" + 
                                        Integer.toString(mm) + ":" + "0" 
                                        + (Integer.toString(ss))
                                );
                            } else {
                                lblClock.setText(Integer.toString(hh) + ":" + 
                                        Integer.toString(mm) + ":" 
                                        + (Integer.toString(ss))
                                );
                            }
                        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }.start();
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by `not stops when boolean run = false` ?

Comment: How it will go inside of the while(run) loop if `run=false` ?

Comment: if i call this method by `countTime(true)` this timer is running and there is a label in my GUI that shows the time. Now i need to stop this timer by calling `countTime(false)`. The boolean parameter `run` is used to run `while loop` .

Answer (score 4):

I am guessing that you are starting the timer like `countTime(true)` and to turn it off you are calling `countTime(false)`.

You did not notice that the `timer` is running as separate thread. So calling again you are launching a new thread. Basically each call will launch a new thread, nothing will be updated in any of the previously running threads.

This is a anonymous `Thread` class which creates a new thread every time you call the `countTime(boolean)` method.

Comment: You can use the [CountDownLatch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) with count one, create only one thread. Change the status of the latch as per your needs

Answer (score 1):

Can you add "**caller**" code & code snippet setting run as false?

From current code, **countTime** starts  a new Thread always. That may be the reason. Did not see where "**run**" was set as false.

Do you want to start new thread always? and How and where are you making **run** as false?

I think that you need only one thread and you have to set **run** value "**true**" or "**false**" from the caller. Posting caller code will help to fix the problem.

**EDIT:**

1) Declare one thread separately. Provide setter and getter method for "run" boolean variable.

2) When user click on start button click of "start", start the thread with run as true.  If user clicks on start twice, make sure that second thread is not created. If (thread == null) create new thread and ignore the request if thread is not null

3) When user click on stop button & thread is not null, set the run as false.

Comment: there are two buttons in the gui, first one is to start the timer and second one is to stop the timer.  Start timer button calls `countTime(true)` and stop timer button calls `countTime(false)`.

Comment: then you need only one thread. set the countdown from action listener of those two buttons

Answer (score 0):

By calling `countTime(false)`,you just start another thread.if you print the time message to the console and click start button twice,you will find there are two timer running.
To stop the thread,you might do like this:

```
Thread thread=new Thread(){
public void run(){
//your timer code here
}};
public synchronized void stop(){
        if(null != thread){
            thread.interrupt();
            thread = null;
            notifyAll();
        }
}
public void start(){
        if(null == thread){
            thread = new Thread(this);
            thread.start();
        }
}
```

when you want to start the thread,call `start()`,and `stop()` to stop it.

why doing so?when the thread is in the blocked state (by calling `Thread.sleep(1000)`) then call `thread.interrupt()` to let it throw the InterruptedException.
I am new to programming too,and had the similar problem,hope that can help you

Comment: Small change. change thread.interrupt() to custom thread class extending Thread cthread.setRun(false) by declaring setRun(boolean status){ run=status;} Controlling Thread life cycle with flags is more efficient than invoking interrupt() or stop()